# Преобразование массива char в число

Tags: c++, строки, преобразование

Написал функцию, которая введенную преобразует в число. Но при выводе пишет, что она хранит не введенное число, а 0. В чем я ошибся?

```
void Input(char *N, int &stopper) 
{
    int i = 0;
    N[i] = getchar();
    while (N[i] != '\n')
    {
        N[i] -= 48;
        i++;
        N[i] = getchar();
    };

    stopper = atoi(N);

    printf("\n");

}
```

Comment: уберите `N[i] -= 48` будет работать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это называется "перестарались".:)

Уберите предложение

```
N[i] -= 48;
```

так как функция `atoi` работает с символьными представлениями чисел.

Я определил бы эту функцию следующим образом

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

int Input( char *s, size_t n )
{
    size_t i = 0;
    char c;

    while (i < n && (c = std::getchar()) != EOF &&  c != '\n')
    {
        s[i++] = c;
    }

    if ( n != 0 ) s[i == n ? n-1 : i] = '\0';

    return std::atoi(s);
}

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    char s[N];
    int x = Input(s, N);

    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: только хотел сказать))+